# StreamReader Read random line

Tags: c#, streamreader

Is there a way to make `StreamReader ReadLine()` in random order through a CSV file?

Example:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\\file.csv"));
String firstName = reader.ReadLine().ToString();
Console.WriteLine(firstName);
```

Comment: Yes there is. Maybe you can tell us what you have tried?

Comment: Can you load the whole file into memory at once? If you can it's easy, if you can't this becomes either very slow or annoying to code.

Answer (score 1):

StreamReader reads sequentially per definition. All I can think of is if the file is not to big

```
var lines File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\file.csv")

Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
List<T> sortedList = lines.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).ToList();
```

Comment: What if your random number is larger than your line count?

Comment: Does not matter. The random number is just for ordering the lines. So in effect it just gets the lines and then assigns a random number to it by which it is ordered.

Comment: I see. I don't know if reading a large file and then ordering all the lines to pick a random line is the best idea?

Comment: It is a very neat solution (if you look over the part that everything is in memory now since I do not know of a way you can really get past this). You can actually have a Shuffle<T> extension method for any type and then just cal it on lines. ie lines.shuffle if you want to randomly iterate through all of them. If he just wants one random line then yeah ... a bit overkill

Comment: His first sentence seems to imply he wants a random order though and not just one line.

Answer (score 0):

Use C#'s [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to generate a random number which you'll use to select a line from your file.

[File.ReadLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not have to read the whole file, you can use LINQ to build a query to filter the lines that it reads:

> Return Value Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable All
>   the lines of the file, or the lines that are the result of a query.

In this case, however, we need to read it all to find the number of lines.

```
// Read lines
string[] lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\file.csv");

// Seed a random number in the range 0 to your count
var r = new Random();
int randomNumber = r.Next(0, lines.Length);

// Read the random line
string line = lines.Skip(randomNumber - 1).Take(1).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `StreamReader` is forward only, there's no way that you can go backwards, but you could read all lines into memory first using [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx):

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\file.csv");
Random rnd = new Random();
List<string> randomLines = new List<string>(allLines.Length);
for(int i = 0; i < allLines.Length ; i++)
{
    randomLines.Add(allLines[rnd.Next(allLines.Length)]);
}
```